# MS Word won’t find replace line breaks or paragraph breaks

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I copy my column from Excel to Word to easily create large arrays for my apps. Using find and replace to swap out manual line breaks with

","
Now that I use the subscription of Office 365 it seems to have stopped working. Whether I chose the line break/paragraph break from their "Format" button or whether I type ^l  or ^p myself. I've even saved the file as plain text and opened that version and still nothing.

If I turn on display everything it shows paragraph marks, and still won't find them. It finds nothing, period!

This used to be the simplest thing to do.

Does anyone know why this is happening now?

Thanks

Comment: Works on Office 2019. Try maybe to [repair Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2769349/repair-process-for-an-office-click-to-run-application-does-not-start).

Comment: @harrymc, "I use the subscription of Office 365"

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Does that mean that "MicrosoftOffice 365" is not found in Control Panel > Programs and Features?

Comment: Since I too have the subscription I tried it on my iPhone and it works. Go figure.

Comment: Did you try ^11 for a line break and ^13 for a paragraph mark?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a full re-install when the repair did nothing for 7 hours and I had to reboot and lost all Microsoft apps.

And now Find and Replace work

Comment: Sorry about that. It might have been less painful to try LibreOffice, about 10 minutes to install and free.